# Cannot find snip & sketch on Win 10 but can run it

Tags: windows-10, snipping-tool

I can run snip and sketch on a Windows 10 machine by using the shortcut: Win-shift-s. However, I cannot see notification when I use it. I have tried all the solutions I can find. I have previously fixed the problem  on another machine of no notification by reloading/resetting snip& sketch. However, on the machine with the problem, snip&sketch is not visible in Settings> Apps and Features. How do I reload/reset snip&sketch when the app is not visible in settings>apps?

Answer (score 0):

These are methods to help with problems of Windows apps :

- Test Windows integrity by running [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html)
- Run System Maintenance Troubleshooter in
  *Settings > Update & Security > Troubleshoot > Additional troubleshooters >
  Windows Store Apps*
- Re-Register apps using PowerShell run as Administrator :

  ```
  Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
  ```
- Update Snip and Sketch : Run Microsoft Store, find Snip & Sketch
  and click on the Update button
- Reset Microsoft Store Process : Run CMD as administratorm
  run the command `WSReset.exe`, then reboot.

Comment: Snip and Sketch is not available in Windows app store - but snipping tool is available - which I find strange since I thought Snip and Sketch replaced the snipping tool.